# Is there a possibility that you can aggregate your total share statistics on posts with the LinkedIn community management API

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I want to be able to see the share statistics API aggregated on posts, so basically instead of retrieving the total you get the total but spread out on the posts you've made. With the country followers API you do the same thing for country. It seems like there is a way of requesting the share statistics on posts but only 1 post per request using the Share URN but I want to GET ALL

Nothing... absolutely nothing and I'm clueless!